# Filenet - How to get the value of F_Webserver in email template

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

I am using CPE 5.2.1 and trying to make use of email templates to send an email notification which has a link to workitem. In that, we have F_Webserver & some other variables and I don't know how to get the values for these field variables. I was thinking that it should be fetched automatically because 'email notification' that sends by default by enabling them has the complete URL but when I use email template it did not fetch that value and shows me URL like this -

{$F_WEBSERVER}/{$F_STEPPROC}?queueName={$F_WORKQUEUE}&wobNum={$F_WobNum}&isoRegion={$F_REGION_NUMBER}

Do I have to hard code the value in email template .MSG file Or shall I get it from somewhere? Please assist me creating the url.

Answer (score 0):

F_WEBSERVER is taken from the PCC. Go to PCC, right click on your workflow system i.e. node below the folder "Workflow Systems" and navigate to Web Applications
There you will see multiple "Web Application". If you are using Workplace/ICN, there should be a value in the next right column

for ex: If you are using workplace then the value should be in the below format

```
http://<AE Server name>:<port>/<Workplace Context name>
```

If this is your template

```
<h1>Test Email template</h1>
    <p>Name: $1</p>
    <p>Acct Number: $2</p>
    <p>Hello, your request for a loan has been $3.</p>
    <p>Have a nice day.</p>
```

then the values should be like `{"John Doe","P34537","Approved"}.`

So now for $1 Joh doe is replaced by FileNet. Uing this approach, filenet won't be able to get the actual value for F_WEBSERVER. If you want this, then you need to edit the templates. Follow this url

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.doc/note/modify_notification.htm

Comment: you are right.. It should be taken from PCC (I learnt this recently from ecmplace) & in my case it's already there for ICN but I can't see it in email when email template is being used. I am using "stp_new.msg" template.